# how i can send and get file by using sftp?

Tags: unix, bash, command-line-interface, sftp, copy

how i can send and get file by using sftp ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an index of SFTP commands. The ones you'll want are GET and PUT.
http://www.cs.unc.edu/help/sftp/commands.html